# What does uniprot consider "unambiguous" evidence for the subcellular domain of a protein?

Tags: cell-biology, bioinformatics, cell-membrane, database

[Uniprot has annotation for subcellular location of protein domains](http://www.uniprot.org/help/topo_dom). This topological domain information of proteins is under the `TOPO_DOM` flag.

In most cases the subcellular location is assigned by rigorous sequence analysis both for the experimentally verified and predicted subcellular locations. Sometimes more reliable information is available...

> ... when the experimental technique used allows the unambiguous
>   assignment of the transmembrane boundary to a particular position
>   (X-ray crystallography, etc.), the ‘Sequence analysis’ qualifier is
>   not added in the topological domain annotation. In this case, the
>   positions of the topological domains can be propagated ‘By
>   similarity’.

What evidence is available that constitutes *"unambiguous assignment"* so that the `by similarity` qualifier can be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following your question, we have updated the documentation for topological domains in UniProtKB:
http://www.uniprot.org/help/topo_dom

I hope you will find it more informative now. Please don't hesitate to contact the UniProt helpdesk if you have any additional questions (or, if you prefer to discuss here, a short note to the helpdesk would help us spot your posting more reliably, since we cannot closely monitor all forums as you may understand).